# How to keep the HTML element aligned when clicked/focused?

Tags: html, css, border, margin

**UPDATE:** Fixed with `margin-bottom: 0px;`
But somehow it still affect the text box size. Larger.

Then if I use `outline` instead of `border`, the border-radius will not work.

I have a problem with the these elements when one of them is clicked/focused,
it's affect the other element's position. It's because the border is larger than the normal size. So how to fix it?

For example: Click on the text area, it'll make the text input move away.
Note: I don't want to use box-shadow. No need to use position property actually.

HTML

```
<h3>Text Area</h3>
<textarea></textarea>
<br />
<h3>Input: Text</h3>
<input type="text" />
```

CSS

```
input{
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border: 3px solid #507ad5;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**UPDATE:** See and test it directly: http://jsfiddle.net/hedaru/dSgxr/6/

Here it is how it supposed to be: goo.gl/jAojK

Comment: Nothing happens when hovered. Do you mean clicked?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, clicked.

Comment: Make sure to same your border width input and Input:foucs it must be same

Comment: @kst Note that's not supposed to be same border style like the normal state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because of this:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border: 2px solid #507ad5;
}
```

If you add another pixel to the border, the element is going to move.

You should keep the border at 1px and change its color.

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #507ad5;
}
```

---

**Update**:

Use margins instead of position, it will fix it in the same place and the borders will "grow" around it. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/JKDQW/).

CSS:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border: 2px solid #507ad5;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Comment: I know it. But I don't want it to be still at 1px, but 2px or more.

Comment: It works. But why it still affect the size? It'll be larger. Here it is how it supposed to be: http://goo.gl/jAojK. But want to be better,  just like a normal button without changing the border size.

Comment: As we've already explained, using a border will make the element bigger. If you don't want to use a border, use an outline instead.

Comment: Yes, but outline can't be affected by border-radius. It makes square style without rounded corners. That's why. So, any other method to make a border just outside the element but not enlarge it?

Comment: I honestly don't think you're going to find another solution. This works fine.

Comment: Okay then for a while. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS specifies the focused elements to be larger than the non-focused versions of the same elements.

Adding a `border` physically grows an element. Either add the same number of pixels of border to your element's base (with white colour) or use `outline`.

Here's my fix: http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/dSgxr/2/

Comment: But it's not affected by the border-radius. Will not like rounded corner, that's why I used border.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (besides merely changing the border colour) is to add a margin that shrinks by the same amount that the border grows. Note that the margin must be large enough to overcome the margin collapse with adjacent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can change the difference in margin. It seems like the margin-bottom of the elements right now is 2px, so when you change it to 0px on focus, you compensate for the growth of the element. Like so:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border: 2px solid #507ad5;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just add "margin: 0px" on the focused one. Just make sure margin+border makes the same number on focused and unfocused.

Comment: Yes it works. But somehow it's affect the text box size. Larger.